# Golang parse JSON array into data structure

Tags: json, parsing, go

I am trying to parse a file which contains JSON data:

```
[
  {"a" : "1"},
  {"b" : "2"},
  {"c" : "3"}
]
```

Since this is a JSON array with dynamic keys, I thought I could use:

```
type data map[string]string
```

However, I cannot parse the file using a `map`:

```
c, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("c")
dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(c))
var d data
dec.Decode(&d)


json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.data
```

What would be the most simple way to parse a file containing a JSON data is an array (only string to string types) into a Go struct?

**EDIT:** To further elaborate on the accepted answer -- it's true that my JSON is an array of maps. To make my code work, the file should contain:

```
{
  "a":"1",
  "b":"2",
  "c":"3"
}
```

Then it can be read into a `map[string]string`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because your json is actually an array of maps, but you're trying to unmarshall into just a `map`. Try using the following:

```
type YourJson struct {
    YourSample []struct {
        data map[string]string
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! This works when the file is the same format as in my question. I edited my question to show the other possibility to make it work with a `map[string]string`.

Comment: Can we have the full working code? I tried with above YourJson struct and not succeeded.

Comment: With this `type YourJson []map[string]string` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466050/248616 works for me

Answer (score 25):

Try this: http://play.golang.org/p/8nkpAbRzAD

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type mytype []map[string]string

func main() {
    var data mytype
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(file, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `type mytype []map[string]string` be type `mytype map[string]string` ?

Answer (score 4):

you can try the bitly's simplejson package
https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson

it's much easier.