# Unmarshaling JSON top level array into map of string to string

Tags: arrays, json, go

I'm trying to unmarshal a JSON array of the following type:

```
[
{"abc's": "n;05881364"},
{"abcoulomb": "n;13658345"},
{"abcs": "n;05881364"}
]
```

into a `map[string]string`. This question [Golang parse JSON array into data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465566/golang-parse-json-array-into-data-structure) almost answered my problem, but mine is a truly map, not an array of maps. Unmarshaling into a `[]map[string]string` worked but I now get a map of `map[string]string`, not a simple `map` of `string` as it should be

Comment: The JSON shown is an array of maps where each map has a single key/value pair. If you want to create a `map[string]string` out of that, you'll have to unmarshal it into an array of maps and then create a single map from that.

Comment: @AndySchweig so there's no direct way?

Comment: @AndySchweig I thought there way a better way instead of looping through every map element and extracting its key and value and adding to a new map

Comment: Whatever you unmarshal into has to have the same structure as the JSON. Why is the JSON structured as an array of maps if it's supposed to be a single map?

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to do it directly with the `json` package; you have to do the conversion yourself. This is simple:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte(`
        [
        {"abc's": "n;05881364"},
        {"abcoulomb": "n;13658345"},
        {"abcs": "n;05881364"}
        ]
    `)

    var mapSlice []map[string]string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &mapSlice); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    resultingMap := map[string]string{}
    for _, m := range mapSlice {
        for k, v := range m {
            resultingMap[k] = v
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(resultingMap)
}
```

Output

```
map[abc's:n;05881364 abcoulomb:n;13658345 abcs:n;05881364]
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (though very similar) to Alex's answer is to define your own type along with an UnmarshalJSON function.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type myMapping map[string]string

func (mm myMapping) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var temp []map[string]string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &temp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, m := range temp {
        for k, v := range m {
            mm[k] = v
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`
            [
                {"abc's": "n;05881364"},
                {"abcoulomb": "n;13658345"},
                {"abcs": "n;05881364"}
            ]`)

    resultingMap := myMapping{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &resultingMap); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resultingMap)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/E91eySGrWk)