# How to decode json in Go

Tags: json, dictionary, go

I have a json look like this

```
[{"name":"Name1","age":20},{"name":"Name2","age":29}]
```

And I want to decode it to map look like this

map[map["name":"Name1" ....] ,map["name":"Name2",....]]

In my case I have a logic look like this

```
bt:= []byte(metadatas[0])
var dat interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(bt, dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(dat)
```

and as a response I am getting

```
[map["name":"Name1" ....] ,map["name":"Name2",....]]
```

How can I get a map instead of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang parse JSON array into data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465566/golang-parse-json-array-into-data-structure)

Answer (score 2):

A target data structure for unmarshaling can be defined as `val := []map[string]interface{}{}`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    input := []byte(`[{"name":"Name1","age":20},{"name":"Name2","age":29}]`)
    val := []map[string]interface{}{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &val); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", val)
}
```

[Go Playgroung](https://play.golang.org/p/usZqVUAhso)

This gives us a slice of maps. If you want to put those maps inside another map, there should be a key for elements of that map (like their indexes in the slice).

Answer (score 1):

By definition `map` is a data structure that keeps a reference to specific values using some predefined keys.

In your case, you're having a data structure called collection (array of maps). If you want to keep your collection items as another map values the easiest way to achieve this is to transform your collection into map using indexes of the array (collection) as keys.

However I'm not sure you would be able to do it straight-head during your `json.Unmarshal` without applying some additional transformations

Answer (score 0):

I have already fix this problem, Here is my logic

```
type Meta struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
}

type Metadata struct {
    Collection []Meta
}


bt:= []byte(metadatas[0])
dat := make([]Meta, 0)
if err := json.Unmarshal(bt, &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

And as a response I am getting array with objects